# Use LINQ inside an HtmlHelper to bind a specific item of a Collection outside a @foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Mvc 5. Let's assume that I have a ViewModel that contains a Collection, like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}
```

In the View, I want to be able to create an input field specific for a a certain item of this Collection using a LINQ expression, like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyItems.First(y => y.Name == "Hello").Id)
```

This code is invalid, of course, but is there a way I can achieve the same result, maybe creating a custom HtmlHelper?

Comment: what about creating a second property in your viewmodel with the getter as x.MyItems.First(y => y.Name == "Hello").  and trying to bind to that in the view

Comment: You might also be able to decorate `MyItems` as a custom `DataType` and provide an `EditorTemplate` to handle the collection. A custom helper should work too

Comment: @Fran I'm interested in that approach but would you be able to elaborate a bit more please? Maybe with a quick example? I couldn't make it work by myself.

Comment: so in MyViewModel add a new property public MyItem MySpecialItem {get { return MyItems.First(y => y.Name == "Hello"; }
The only problem is that you are trying to create a textboxfor on an object and not a propery of an object.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, the TextBoxFor is for some property of the object. But still, my problem is on Post: should I manually make the binding in the controller after posting the form? This would be dreadful, I'm afraid. The project I'm working on is huge and this problem will happen a lot of times. I was looking for some sort of automated solution.

Comment: I think i understand what your are doing but it's not really clear from your original post.  Why not send the full list to the view and just iterate all the items in the list and then bind each one the way you want.  This is an old link which may work for you  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: The last part helped me. I can set a custom Index with a hidden field to identify the specific element I want to bind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to change `ICollection<MyItem>` to `IList<MyItem>` and then in your View:

```
var myItemIndex = Model.MyItems.IndexOf(Model.MyItems.First(y => y.Name == "Hello"));
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyItems[myItemIndex].Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand what your are doing but it's not really clear from your original post. Why not send the full list to the view and just iterate all the items in the list and then bind each one the way you want. This is an old link which may work for you [haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)